# Why does Boolean Function that returns false return true

Tags: c, vb.net

I have this C function inside of a dll that I am calling from VB.Net.

C code:

```c
extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) bool __stdcall C(bool ret);
}

extern bool __stdcall C(bool ret){
    return ret;
}
```

Here is my VB.Net code that calls the above:

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Module Module1

    <DllImport("foo.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Private Function C(ByVal param As Boolean) As Boolean
    End Function

    Sub Main()
        System.Console.WriteLine("C(False): {0}", C(False))
        System.Console.WriteLine("C(True): {0}", C(True))
    End Sub

End Module
```

When I run the above code, I get:

```
C(False): True
C(True): True
```

It appears we aren't actually returning the value from `C()`, but rather we are returning the fact that `C()` runs successfully.

**Why does `C()` always return `true`?
And when would C() not run successfully?**

If you have any other information about this phenomenon then please give me your answer :).This was all off the top of my head. Cheers.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Please rephrase your question. To clarify, you _are_ checking the return value of the function.. because the statement is a conditional statement and the value that is placed there is the boolean return value of the function.

Comment: You state "we arnt actually returning the value from C() we are checking if C() runs successfully.".  That is *not* true as Simon said. The confusion may come from a common convention on many platforms to return a value that will evaluate to true if a function call does what it was supposed to do, and to return something that will evaluate to false if the function call fails.  A value is still being returned, it's just that the value follows a useful convention.

Comment: If the function *doesn't* "run successfully", you'll know about it when your program catches an exception or crashes.

Comment: -1: random bits of code in unknown language (I don't see any C#-like code... some C-like code is present, but not real C/C++; some possibly VB.Net code? )

Comment: you have `C` defined once taking a string arg, then that bit at the bottom arg is a boolean.  I dont think that sig at the top is right.  See PInvoke for oodles of examples.

Comment: In your next post, please post a simple, complete C++ example that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @Mr.Google - I reworked your example to be more complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Why does C() always return true?**

I found a Microsoft Connect issue which talks about returning `bool`, and why it behaves the way it does. This is from the issue [Native C++ function returning bool always return true in .NET Interop](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/355665/native-c-function-returning-bool-always-return-true-in-net-interop):

> you need to decorate the P/Invoke declaration with [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]. 
>   Bool marshals to Win32 BOOL - which is a 4-byte value .... Your function returns a 1-byte bool ... so any garbage in the upper 24 bits ... will be interpreted as 'true' by the marshaling layer.

So in other words, the VB `Boolean` type is incorrectly getting mapped to a Win 32 `BOOL` (4 bytes), which is not the same as a C boolean (1 byte).

To fix this you can do *one* of these two things:

**Option 1 - Change the VB P/Invoke Signature**

You can tell the marshalling code to map to a one byte `bool`.

This line in the VB P/Invoke signature:

```vb
Private Function C(ByVal param As Boolean) As Boolean
```

should be changed to:

```vb
Private Function C(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)> ByVal param As Boolean) As _
<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)> Boolean
```

**Option 2 - Change the C Function Signature**

You can change the C one-byte `bool` type to a Win 32 four-byte `BOOL`, as follows:

```c
extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) BOOL __stdcall C(BOOL ret);
}

extern BOOL __stdcall C(BOOL ret){
    return ret;
}
```

**Results**

If I run your program with either one of the changes above, the output is:

```
C(False): False
C(True): True
```

The return values now reflect the parameter values.

---

> **And when would C() not run successfully?**

Your code, as written will generally run successfully. The only case where I can think of it failing is if the 
VB.Net code cannot find the C binary. In this case an exception will be thrown; if you don't catch the exception, your application will be terminated.

Comment: Excellent answer, and deserving of more for having turned the question into an excellent question.

Comment: Excellent chue! I just hopped back into the project i was working on. Option 2 seems to fix the issue i was having